# GCM conflict between Android App and Android Library

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm building a library that uses GCM. I was testing it with a sample app that implements GCM as well.

I have used same implementation for both except every one of them has its own sender ID

That's what I wrote for my sample app I'm testing the library with. I also wrote same thing for the library but with different names for the services:

```
<!-- GCM -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.example.instabug" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".SampleInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".SampleGcmRegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <service
        android:name=".SampleGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>

    </service>
```

My problem is whenever I sent a push notification to my library the App receiver always catch it. the library receiver don't do anything.

Is there a way to resolve this issue?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out someway to do that. In my Android library I gave the intent filter of `GcmListenerService`  a higher priority than the one is in the Android app so that the GCM message received and processed by the library first.

```
<service
    android:name=".SampleGcmListenerService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter priority="100">
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>

</service>
```

When the GCM message arrive to the library's `GcmListenerService` you have to forward to the android app if it's irrelevant to the library. Since I'm making a library that can be used by anyone in the future. I will not know where can I find the `GcmListenerService` in the the app module. All I can do is to use reflection to get all classes in the app module and see which one has `GcmListenerService` as a super class and then starting a wakeful service to that class.

Here what I did:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

    if (!from.equalsIgnoreCase("51XXXXXXXX")) {
        String[] classes = getClassesOfPackage(getPackageName());
        for (int i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
            String sClassName = classes[i];
            try {
                Class classToInvestigate = Class.forName(sClassName);

                String superClassName = classToInvestigate.getSuperclass().getName();
                if (superClassName.equalsIgnoreCase("com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService")) {

                    //sending intent to the wakeful app's service
                    forwardGcmToApp(from, data, sClassName);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } else {
        //TODO: fire the polling service
        String message = data.getString("message");
    }
}

/**
 * Called to get list of classes included in the current project
 *
 * @param packageName the name of application package
 * @return array of classes' names
 */
private String[] getClassesOfPackage(String packageName) {
    ArrayList<String> classes = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        String packageCodePath = getPackageCodePath();
        DexFile df = new DexFile(packageCodePath);
        for (Enumeration<String> iter = df.entries(); iter.hasMoreElements(); ) {
            String className = iter.nextElement();
            if (className.contains(packageName)) {
                classes.add(className);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return classes.toArray(new String[classes.size()]);
}

/**
 * Called to forward Gcm content to the App {@link GcmListenerService}
 *
 * @param from Gcm sender ID
 * @param data bundle received from Gcm
 * @param className Class name that extends {@link GcmListenerService}
 */
private void forwardGcmToApp(String from, Bundle data, String className){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");

    data.putString("from", from);
    data.putString("message_type", null);

    intent.putExtras(data);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(getPackageName(), className));

    GcmReceiver.startWakefulService(getApplicationContext(), intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you have two services with same intent filter. In that case Android will pick the service with higher priority (foreground). If priority is the same - will pick random, i.e. just one service will receive the intent.

For your case best solution will be to use just one service and dispatch according to `from` (senderId) parameter of `onMessageReceived()` in your `GcmListenerService`.